# does runOnUiThread runs continuously

Tags: android-runonuithread

i have an Init_Params function which would be called from outside of the class, so i have done it like this below. which works fine.
i need to know, is this runOnUiThread running in background continuously or run once when i called.
i need to run it once on startup

```js
public void Init_Params()
    {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
  {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    second_t1 = 0; second_t2 = 0;
    t_delta = 0;  second_rec = 0;
    rec_size = 0;  iteration_cuntr = 0; start_delay = 0;
    run_flag = 0; Min_width = 100; Sec_width = 50; Sec_count = 0;
    Threshold = (float)0.9;
    Processing_time = 0;
   }
  });
    }
```

Comment: from where you are calling `Init_Params()` method ?

Comment: i am calling it once in oncreat of my main activity.